# What does "A" logging indicator mean in Websphere?

Tags: websphere

What does "A" logging indicator mean in IBM Websphere Process Server?

Comment: Quick web search would provide the short description. If you're looking for more detail on that particular audit level with that product, you should probably modify the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a list of message types in WebSphere logs and traces;

- `1,2,3` Trace info: fine, finer, finest
- `￼A` Audit ￼
- `W` Warning
- `￼Z` Type was not recognized
- ￼`E` Error
- ￼`D` Detail ￼
- `C` Configuration
- ￼`F` Fatal (exits process)
- ￼`I` Information
- `￼O` Program output
- ￼`R` Program output (sys.err)