# What does this figure mean in the log file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, websphere

I wonder what the part `0000002a` means where log output looks like this:

`[2012-10-09 10:37:17:229 CEST] 0000002a EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.daos.AnstalldDAO interface of the AnstalldDAOImpl enterprise bean in the PandoraArendeProcessEJB.jar module of the PandoraArendeEar application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.daos.AnstalldDAO``

My log4j config is

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, DATEDFILE, CONSOLE

### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.DATEDFILE=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Prefix=arendeprocess.
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Suffix=.log
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Directory=//localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeprocess/
```

Comment: That output doesn't match _either_ of your conversion patterns, hence it's coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like standard WebSphere process log output which has the format below;

```
<timestamp><threadId><shortName><eventType>[className][methodName]<textmessage> [parameter 1] [parameter 2]
```

So  `0000002a` is the thread identifier (which thread is causing the output). Other fields are self explanatory. For eventType check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739322/what-does-a-logging-indicator-mean-in-websphere).